# Mousemove gets slower when you move fast with mouse

Tags: jquery, performance, mousemove, mousedown, mouseup

im trying to make jquery box drag, but the problem is that when i drag really fast the "mousemove" is moving slower than my mouse and when the mouse gets out of the dragging #box the mousemove wont move, how can i fix this?:

```
function position(div,x,y) {

    x = x-100;
    y = y-100;

    $(div).css({'left':x, 'top':y});

}


$(document).ready(function() {

    var check = false;

    $("#box").mousedown(function() {

        check = true;

        $("#box").mousemove(function (e) {

            if(check != false) {

                position("#box", e.pageX, e.pageY);

            }

        });

    }).mouseup(function() {

        check = false;

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's slowing down because you are using too many system resouces.  So you need to find ways to reduce system usage.

By delagating the mousemove to document, it runs a bit faster.  It still lags a bit when you move the mouse really fast, but it's an improvement.  Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var check = false,
        box = $("#box")[0];

    $(box).mousedown(function() {
        check = true;
    }).mouseup(function() {
        check = false;
    });

    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        if(check) {
            position(box, e.pageX, e.pageY);
        }   
    });
});
```

Comment: That was my point :P `.style.left` won't work on a jQuery object.

Comment: It's not a jquery object.. it's a dom element - this in mousemove is a dom element. But yes, there's an error.  Gimme a sec..

Comment: Blender, it's actually the opposite problem — "box" isn't a jQuery object, but "mousemove" is a jQuery method, so it was breaking. Box is just a DOM node, and running style.left on it is a much more efficient way of setting this prop than using CSS - http://jsperf.com/style-versus-jquery-css

Comment: @doug - exactly.. but the way his code is set it, it's still slow.. I'm playin around with it.  I'll check out your fiddle in a sec

Comment: Great to hear it! Ps: we at SO love points. In fact, we are addicts. Upvotes (the up arrow) and accepting questions spreads the love.